# Forward Slash issue with DBI

Tags: perl, dbi

I'm new to using DBI for SQL queries in a perl script.  The issue I'm having pertains to data in fields that have a forward slash.  I'm wanting to use variables as input for my where clause, but it is doing what DBI intends a forward slash to do: stop the query.  I tried numerous different work arounds from binds, quotes, etc. but none worked, is it even possible?  Data in this is consistent. The line with the my $sql variable is where the trouble is.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Modules
use DBI;
use DBD::Oracle;
use strict;
use warnings;

# Connection Info
$platform = "Oracle";
$database = "mydb";
$user = "user";
$pw = "pass";

# Data Source
$ds = "dbi:Oracle:$database";

my $dbh = DBI->connect($ds, $user, $pw);

# my $dbh = DBI->connect();       
my $XCOD = $dbh->quote('cba');
my $a = $dbh->quote('abc');
my $b = $dbh->quote('123');
# tried this as well  my $pid = $dbh->quote('$a/$b');
my $sql = "SELECT P_ID FROM MyTable WHERE P_ID=$a/$b AND XCOD=$XCOD";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(); 

my $outfile = 'superunique.txt';
open OUTFILE, '>', $outfile or die "Unable to open $outfile: $!";

while(my @re = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
print OUTFILE @re,"\n";
}

close OUTFILE;

$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();
```

Comment: Have you tried `my $pid = $dbh->quote("$a/$b");`, so interpolation actually happens?

Comment: I had not; however, it doesn't help me.  Figure that I need a value like P_ID='abc/123' which would mean the forward slash would not be included in single ticks when done that way.

Comment: Can you clarify that?  Perhaps give an example of how you tried it with bound variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't like to see folks use variable interpolation in SQL queries. Try using placeholders:

```
 [ snip ]
 my $P_ID = "$a/$b"
 my $sql = "SELECT P_ID FROM MyTable WHERE P_ID = ? AND XCOD = ?";
 my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
 $sth->execute($P_ID, $XCOD); 
 [ snip ]
```

Comment: I have deleted out the unnecessary quotes and changed to my $variable = 'value'; however when i go to run my script I now receive DBD::Oracle:db prepare failed: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended <DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator in 'SELECT P_ID FROM MyTable WHERE P_ID = :p1 <*>XCOD = :p2'>

Comment: there's no 'AND' in the where clause of your error message. check your actual code.

Comment: By the end of dealing with a problem, the obvious seems to vanish.  Didn't return any results, but no errors anymore, so I'll see if I can't tinker around further to get what I should expect back.

Answer (score 4):

You have been given the correct solution to your problem ([use placeholders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31465529/7231)) but you might be interested to see why what you are doing doesn't work.

The problem is that you seem to misunderstand the `quote` method. [The documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#quote) says this:

> Quote a string literal for use as a literal value in an SQL statement,
>   by escaping any special characters (such as quotation marks) contained
>   within the string and adding the required type of outer quotation
>   marks.

You use `quote` in these three lines.

```
my $XCOD = $dbh->quote('cba');
my $a = $dbh->quote('abc');
my $b = $dbh->quote('123');
```

It would be instructive to print out the values of `$XCOD`, `$a` and `$b` (as an aside `$a` and `$b` are really bad names for variables - apart from their non-descriptive nature, they are also special variables used in sorting).

I suspect that you'll see `"cba"`, `"abd"` and `"123"`. The method has found no special characters to escape, so all it has done is to add quote marks around the strings.

You then interpolate these values into your SQL.

```
my $sql = "SELECT P_ID FROM MyTable WHERE P_ID=$a/$b AND XCOD=$XCOD";
```

Again, you should take a close look at what `$sql` contains after this statement has been executed. It will look something like this:

`SELECT P_ID FROM MyTable WHERE P_ID="abc"/"123" AND XCOD="cba"`

It's probably the first part of the WHERE clause that is a problem. Oracle is treating that as a division. And who knows what Oracle does when you divide one string by another. So you end up looking for a row where P_ID is some strange (perhaps undefined) value.

So this looks to be an example where the simplest of debugging techniques (a few `print` statements in the code) would have guided you in the right direction.